# Java string split() Regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string like this,

```
["[number][name]statement_1.","[number][name]statement_1."]
```

i want to get only `statement_1` and `statement_2`. I used tried in this way,

```
String[] statement = message.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

but it gives `["[number][name]statement_1."` and `"[number][name]statement_2."]` . how can i get only `statement_1` and `statement_2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Match All instead of Splitting**

Splitting and Match All are two sides of the same coin. In this case, Match All is easier.

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=\])[^\[\]"]+(?=\.)
```

See the matches in [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/46).

In Java code:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\])[^\\[\\]\"]+(?=\\.)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(yourString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // the match: regexMatcher.group()
}
```

**In answer to your question to get both matches separately:**

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\])[^\\[\\]\"]+(?=\\.)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(yourString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    String theFirstMatch: regexMatcher.group()
} 
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    String theSecondMatch: regexMatcher.group()
}
```

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<=\])` asserts that what precedes the current position is a `]`
- `[^\[\]"]+` matches one or more chars that are not `[`, `]` or `"`
- The lookahead `(?=\.)` asserts that the next character is a dot

**Reference**

- [Match All and Split are Two Sides of the Same Coin](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#splitvsmatch)
- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: FYI: added regex demo, explanation and reference. Please let me know if you have questions.:)

Comment: why are you use while(){} loop ??

Comment: The `find()` method only returns one match. To get all the matches, we iterate with a while loop. This is the standard way of getting all matches in Java. :)

Comment: how can i get statement_1 and statement_2 seperately ??

Comment: Added a section called `In answer to your question to get both matches separately` Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Answer deserves my 2 up-votes for each part but I can do it only once +1

Answer (score 2):

I somehow don't think that is your actual string, but you may try the following.

```
String s = "[\"[number][name]statement_1.\",\"[number][name]statement_2.\"]";
String[] parts = s.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "").split("\\W+");
System.out.println(parts[0]); //=> "statement_1"
System.out.println(parts[1]); //=> "statement_2"
```

Comment: print not gives statement_1 and statement_2 only. it gives [string, string,...] like this

Comment: how can i get statement_1 and statement_2 separately ??

Comment: but the problem is statement_1 and statement_2 contains more than one word. they are statements.

Comment: Well next time, perhaps it would be great to post your actual string data.

Answer (score 1):

is the string going to be for example [50][James]Loves cake?

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ("Enter string");

    String s = scan.nextLine();

    int last = s.lastIndexOf("]")+1;

    String x  = s.substring(last, s.length());

    System.out.println (x);


Enter string
[21][joe]loves cake
loves cake
```

Process completed.

Comment: it's formatted weird but try it let us know if that's what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex instead.

**With Java 7**

```
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^.*\\])(.+)?");

    final String[] strings = { "[number][name]statement_1.", "[number][name]statement_2." };

    final List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (final String string : strings) {
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            results.add(matcher.group(2));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(results);
```

**With Java 8**

```
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^.*\\])(.+)?");

    final String[] strings = { "[number][name]statement_1.", "[number][name]statement_2." };

    final List<String> results = Arrays.stream(strings)
            .map(pattern::matcher)
            .filter(Matcher::matches)
            .map(matcher -> matcher.group(2))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(results);
```